# Sparc assembly - Global registers not consistent throughout functions call

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, sparc

I am currently working on a simple SPARC assembly code which computes the factorial of 5.
I would like to know why the global registers that I used are not consistent througout function calls.

With the traditionnal version using of local registers and the output/input parameters (into %o0), I have no problem, the code works fine,

but when I want to use another version with global registers, I have this issue of consistency.

Here's the code :

```
.data
.LLC0: .asciz "fact(5) = %d\n"

.text
.global main

main:
      save %sp, -96, %sp

      set 5, %g1               ! value 5 into %g1 register
      sethi %hi(.LLC0), %g2
      or %g2, %lo(.LLC0), %o0
      mov %g1, %o1
      call printf
       nop

      mov %g1, %o0             ! set %g1 into parameter for fact function
      call fact
       nop

      mov %o0, %g4
      sethi %hi(.LLC0), %g3
      or %g3, %lo(.LLC0), %o0
      mov %g4, %o1
      call printf
       nop
      ret

fact:
      addcc %g1, -1, %g1       ! current index of the procedure - 
                               ! supposed to be decremented at each call -
      be term                  ! PROBLEM : %g1 always set to 0 before decrement
       nop

      sethi %hi(.LLC0), %g2
      or %g2, %lo(.LLC0), %o0
      mov %g1, %o1
      call printf              ! printf the value of %g1 :
                               ! still equal to -1 at execution
       nop

      call fact
       nop
      mov %o0, %g2
      umul %g2, %g1, %g2
      mov %g2, %i0
      ret

term: set 1, %o0
      ret
```

My problem is that, into `fact` function, the global register `%g1` is set to `0` at each call, so that the print of `%g1` gives always `-1` at execution.

From this [link](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ricko/CSE131/GenAndFPNotes.html), I thought that global registers were persistent throughout functions call, i.e their scope were global and shared by any function in the code.

For example, here, I put `set 5, %g1` in main section and normally, I should get `4` for the printed value in `fact` function.

If anyone could see what's wrong ?

Thanks

UPDATE:

call printf uses %o0 and %o1, not %g1. I still have problems with the scope of global registers (%g5-g7). Here is an example using them like this :

```
.data
.LLC0: .asciz "fact(5) = %d\n"

.text
.global main

main:
      save %sp, -120, %sp

      set 5, %g5
      sethi %hi(.LLC0), %g2
      or %g2, %lo(.LLC0), %o0
      mov %g5, %o1
      call printf
       nop

      mov %g5, %o0
      call fact
       nop

      mov %o0, %g7
      sethi %hi(.LLC0), %g3
      or %g3, %lo(.LLC0), %o0
      mov %g7, %o1
      call printf
       nop
      ret
       restore

fact:
      addcc %g5, -1, %g5
      be term
       nop

      sethi %hi(.LLC0), %g2
      or %g2, %lo(.LLC0), %o0
      mov %g5, %o1
      call printf
       nop

      call fact
       nop
      mov %o0, %g6
      smul %g6, %g5, %g6
      mov %g6, %o0
      ret

term: set 1, %o0
      ret
```

In this code, I print the value of `global %g5 register` at each recursive call and the output is :

```
fact(5) = 5
fact(5) = 838860799
fact(5) = 838860798
fact(5) = 838860797
fact(5) = 838860796
fact(5) = 838860795
fact(5) = 838860794
fact(5) = 838860793
fact(5) = 838860792
fact(5) = 838860791
fact(5) = 838860790
...
```

seems like the first call of fact from main make lose the initial value for `%g5` (initialized to `5`)

Where is my error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SPARC Assembly Language Reference Manual (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28387/toc.html)

6.2 Register Usage

> The global registers %g0-%g7 are more complicated. The %g0 register is always zero. The **%g6 and %g7 are always reserved for the operating system**, so assembly code should not modify them. The other global registers, **%g1-%g5, are caller saves**, and are usable by applications code. But note that %g1 and %g5 may be used in the program linkage table (PLT) or other interposition code, and thus cannot be used to pass parameters from caller to callee.

(my emphasis)

I think your problem is that "Consistent throughout functions call" means that the call and return instructions (et al) do not affect the registers (with register window shifting) but that the **calling convention** does allow the callee to alter the registers, and hence the contents may not survive a call.

Answer (score 0):

`%g1 - %g4 are volatile` – your call to `printf` overrides the value you put into `%g1` earlier, because `printf`’s implementation also uses it.